# How to aligning textviews on the left and right side of a linearlayout

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

According to below codes

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                  android:layout_marginTop="15dip">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="نوع"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/txt_type" />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="تاریخ: ۱۳۹۲/۰۳/۲۸"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:id="@+id/txt_date" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

TextViews are not well aligned and both are not in exact line.

It's like what exactly showed in below picture.

[image]

Comment: Used `relativeLayout` for that.

Comment: why? is not possible with LinearLayout?

Comment: make android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: i can't understand your problem... what you want to do??

Comment: @MD I used relativelayout but nothing is changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the parent layout and try to set orientation to horizontal.  I tried different cases but found that its working in all cases...

[image]